# Magento 2: Reflect CSS Changes Directly

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2 Theme Modification. Whenever we make chages in theme css less files. 
our changes are not reflect directly.

`Developer mode` is already enabled. To show the changes, we have the following options:

**Option 1.** clear Static file cache from backend.

**Option 2.** Remove all files from `pub/static/` folder except `.htaccess` file, So that required files automatically generated.

**Option 3.** run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command

**My question is:** Is there any other option so that When I make changes in the theme `less css` file, It will automatically reflect ?

I tried to search on the web but didn't find any answer. Some people suggested to directly work in pub/static file css and then copy in theme css file. I think this is Not recommended and not as per standard.

Answer (score 1):

My workflow local with Developer Mode set and changing less files is:
1. remove everything in Folder var/view_preprocessed/
2. remove everything in Folder pub/static/frontend/your Vendor/your theme/
3. clean cache

it´s almost equal to Devdocs from Magento http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html

Works great for me with Version 2.0.4

Also see this Post here on Stackexchange [Magento2: Best practice to modify css files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96468/magento2-best-practice-to-modify-css-files)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you need to clear the two folders to reflect the changes in the styles

```
 pub/static 

 var/view_preprocessed
```

You can read the related info in the below Magento dev docs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/cache_for_frontdevs.html

I just wrote a small bash script in the Magento root to clear the cache (clearCache.sh)

```
cd pub/static
pwd
rm -rf *
cd ../../var/view_preprocessed
pwd
rm -rf *
```

In your command line

```
sh clearCache.sh
```