# Magento 2.2.6 overriding css or less files or locating the actual file to edit

Tags: css, static-content, less-css

Not sure why i'm finding this so difficult but I have a file that has some css that needs to be fixed. The file and code are in these files:

```
pub/static/frontend/website/mywebsite/en_US/css/styles-l.min.css
var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/mywebsite/en_US/css/styles-l.min.css
```

The style change i need to make is only on `checkout/cart/` as well.

I looked for this same styles-l.min.css file in app/design/frontend/website/mywebsite/ but it's no where to be found.

I know i'm not suppose to edit those files but when i edit those files directly i get the outcome that i want... but of course when i deploy it gets rinsed. How do i make the proper change?

Not much of a frontend guy so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: have a look on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155539/magento-2-style-m-css-vs-style-l-css?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

The file is being inherited from the parent theme. If you bring into your theme after you static-content-deploy your version will be used instead.

Depending on what mode magento is in you might need to delete the file in view_preprocessed.

If in doubt search in /vendor folder for styles-l.css

Should be inside a magento blank theme folder.

Comment: so you're saying bring it into my theme inside of app/design/frontend/company/theme/ ??? and then what.. Magento_Checkout? or Magento_Cart/web/css/ <<< something like that? @Dominic Xigen

Comment: Yes sorry not the easiest thing to explain.  I kid you not I had this problem on an install this morning.  The error was complaining about `magento-invitation/web/css/source/_module.less` so I created a blank `/app/design/frontend/Xigen/Theme/Magento_Invitation/web/css/source/_module.less`.  Although your issue is slightly different.  You might need to take a style-l.css file from vendor folder and put it into your theme.