# CSS resets to start point after flush a cache

Tags: css

Ok, this is weird.

I bought a template, and when I change something in the CSS, and after flush the cache, or make some changes in the blocks, the CSS gets reset!

I thought changing the permissions would do the trick, but I was wrong.

Comment: What Magento version?

Comment: what is the location of your `css` file, in which you are doing editing if it is present in pub folder then you are working on a wrong place instead of editing there edit in the css available into your app/design folder present in the web content of your theme

Comment: root instalation/app/design/Frontend/themevendor/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making changes to your cached files which are rebuild when you flush your cache.

---

If you use Magento 1, is the path to the `CSS` file your are changing similar to:

```
www.domain.com/media/css_secure/
```

If so, you are editing the cached `CSS` which will also be overwritten when you flush your cache.

As a first step, I would read this PDF from Magento about Designing a theme. http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

---

If you use Magento 2, is the path to the `CSS` file your are changing similar to:

```
www.domain.com/static/frontend/themevendor/theme/locale/css
```

If so, you are editing the compiled `CSS`.

I would suggest reading this thread on how to edit CSS in Magento 2: [Magento2: Best practice to modify css files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96468/magento2-best-practice-to-modify-css-files)

Comment: Yes there is the root on the css I´d changed the css.