# How to edit .less or css files

Tags: magento2, css, less, styles

I like to change some styles in my website, so i edited .less and CSS files

for example:

```
 app/design/frontend/Templatemonster/theme/web/css/styles-l.less
```

I used "flush Magento cache" from backend still my modified files not updated. 
What can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: if it is in production mode run static content deployment

Comment: @mohana check reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96480/68695

Comment: If i'm in developer mode, how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile less using Grunt. You can find detailed description of configure grunt [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

You can also run below commands from Magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks