# Magento 2.3 - CSS changes revert after running " php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f "

Tags: css, magento2.3.4, less-css

After edited CSS then run  **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** my changes revert, all my css workout removed.

> CSS Path :
> pub/static/frontend/Codazon/fatest_grocery_gourmet/en_US/css/style-l.css

Best practice to edit CSS files?

Comment: pub/static files are regenerated everytime you run this commands

Comment: if you are using phpstorm then you can check your css changes in history and get back

Comment: check my ans on how to use custom css in magento 2

Comment: Follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96468/magento2-best-practice-to-modify-css-files

Answer (score 2):

Did you changed the CSS in pup/static folder.If you did it is wrong. You need to change it's related less or css file in module/theme. After that run the required commands.

Answer (score 2):

You should not edit/modify files within pub/* or vendor/* directory. Pub is for deployment and vendor is for default structure, which you override via your template or custom modules. Instead:

- Create a new theme inside app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{yourTheme}/.
  You can use Blank or Luma theme. You can also create new theme which inherites from Blank (inheritance is defined within theme.xml). If you are already using some theme then skip this step.
- Edit .less
  within your theme so the changes stay visible and don't get replaced when clearing the cache or upgrading the system.
- Use grunt to compile your .less into deployment files.
- You can also setup sourcemaps to pin point your styling within the theme .less files so you can be more productive.

Some useful references:

- [Getting started with Less](http://lesscss.org/)
- [Less debugging in Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)
- [Create a theme in Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
- [Getting started with Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
- [Magento UI Library](https://magebr.github.io/Magento-2-UI-library/index.html)

FYI: [Magento2: Best practice to modify css files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96468/magento2-best-practice-to-modify-css-files)

Comment: From your point " edit .less " where it is located?

Comment: Here "edit" is not a file name. it means if you need to edit and less file then you do in your theme/child theme.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Create **default_head_blocks.xml** like below locations in your theme

**app/design/frontend/Test/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**
and add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/yourcustomstyle.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

**Step 2**: **`create your css file at below locations`**

**app/design/frontend/Test/Theme/web/css/yourcustomstyle.css**

**Step 3**:- **now go to pub/static/frontend and delete everything inside frontend folder.**

**now run below commands**

```
<root>php bin/magento setup:upgrade

<root>php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f

<root>php bin/magento cache:Clean
```